# Need help with getting auth token from Postman

Tags: oauth2

I need some help with getting Auth Token through Postman. Based on  https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&language=en_US I have constructed a request [image: getAuthToken] . cs10 - is the right sales force instance, query params are also correct, but something is wrong. Not sure what is missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but I have recently faced a similar issue and I thought I would rather post a more detailed answer than the one I posted initially.

I managed to get authentication via Postman. The key for me was to create a [Connected app] (https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=connected_app_overview.htm) and to connect using the "authorization code" grant type in OAuth.

I also wrote a step-by-step guide here:

http://blog.mkorman.uk/using-postman-to-explore-salesforce-restful-web-services/

Comment: Its better if you add a update section in your original answer instead of posting two different answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you appended your security token to your password in the "password" field? I was getting the same error until I added it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @crmprogdev this is a valid answer

Comment: @BrianMansfield. I "tagged" it when it came up in the queue because it appeared that it would have been more appropriate to post it as a comment rather than as an answer. Due to it's phrasing, it seemed to be asking for more information than it was providing in terms of answering the question. Just my `$0.02`.